Laplace transform schema
I am looking for shared TikZ examples to create something similar to the following figure:

I searched on TSE and Googled but couldn’t find anything relevant.
Does anyone have ideas on how to create something like this using TikZ or another LaTeX package? I don’t necessarily need a full code—just a starting point would be helpful.
Update: Here what I managed to do using just plain math and no tikz.
\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
    & \text{ODE in } t & \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}} & \text{eqn. in } s & \\[1em]
    \{ & \downarrow & & \downarrow & \} \\
    & y(t) & \xleftarrow{\mathcal{L}^{-1}} & Y(s) &
\end{array}
\]


Maybe have a look at tikz-cd? Then you could enclose it in curly braces

@Jasper I posted my workaround solution. Thanks for your comment.

The following code tries to reproduce the desired effect as much as possible:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\biggg}{\bBigg@{3}}
\makeatother
\def\bigggl{\mathopen\biggg}
\def\bigggr{\mathclose\biggg}
\begin{document}

\[ \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{\text{original}}{\text{space}}
\bigggl\{
  \begin{tikzcd}
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{\text{ODE}}{\text{in }t}
    \arrow[r,"\mathcal{L}"] \arrow[d, dashed] 
    & \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{\text{eqn.}}{\text{in }s} \arrow[d] \\
    y(t) \arrow[r,leftarrow,swap,"\mathcal{L}^{-1}"] & Y(s)
  \end{tikzcd}
\bigggr\}
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{\text{transform}}{\text{space}} \]

\end{document}



Maybe tikzcd will enable fancier stuff, but you can just use amsmath --- by the way, please post a complete compilable example next time...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{\text{original}}{\text{space}}
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{ccccc}
            & \text{ODE in } t & \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}} & \text{eqn. in } s & \\[1em]
            & \downarrow & & \downarrow &  \\
            & y(t) & \xleftarrow{\mathcal{L}^{-1}} & Y(s) &
        \end{array}
    \right\}
    \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{\text{transform}}{\text{space}}
\]
\end{document}



My workaround solution; not using Tikz though.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{Origin space}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\text{ODE in } t & \xrightarrow{\mathscr{L}} & \text{eqn. in } s \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
y(t) & \xleftarrow{\mathscr{L}^{-1}} & Y(s)
\end{Bmatrix}
\text{Transformed space}
\]

\end{document}



+1 imho, I consider this the best solution, as it will work out of the box in MathJax, and can be navigated well with assistive technology. #accessibility

Use tikz-cd. In order to get good alignment, one has to slightly raise the baseline, but it's not difficult.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} origin \\ space \end{tabular}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} ODE \\ in $t$ \end{tabular}
    \arrow[r,"\mathcal{L}"] \arrow[d,dashed] &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} eqn. \\ in $s$ \end{tabular}
    \arrow[d] \\
    y(t) & Y(s) \arrow[l,"\mathcal{L}^{-1}"]
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{array}
\right\}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} transform \\ space \end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}


With shorter braces:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} origin \\ space \end{tabular}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \noalign{\vspace{-1.1ex}}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} ODE \\ in $t$ \end{tabular}
    \arrow[r,"\mathcal{L}"] \arrow[d,dashed] &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} eqn. \\ in $s$ \end{tabular}
    \arrow[d] \\
    y(t) & Y(s) \arrow[l,"\mathcal{L}^{-1}"]
  \end{tikzcd}\\ \noalign{\vspace{-1.5ex}}
\end{array}
\right\}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} transform \\ space \end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}



I’d make the braces smaller so they only cover the diagram itself, not the arrow indices.

@Gaussler Added, but I don't see a real improvement.

When it comes to delimiters in TeX, the motto should be “as minimal as possible”.
